# Legend symbol is not visable in Layout Composer when styling points with two different attributes

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, print-composer, legend

In QGIS 3.10.2 I have a map that I want to show points by colour using one category and size by another. I have tried to follow the instructions here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#proportional-symbol-and-multivariate-analysis. This I have done but a consequence is that in the Layout composer the legend symbol is either missing or very tiny.

This is my map with just a colour classification:

[image: Just a colour classification]

I then add the instructions to re-size by a second attribute (I converted a 4 category variable into the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 and called it SizePoint)

[image: To add a second classification by size]

Now the legend in the Layout composer does not show a dot at all

[image: Missing legend dot]

Now here this isn't a problem because all the dots are of the same INSTANCE. But there are other maps where there are more than one instance:

[image: Missing two legend dots]

You will see that there is no indication in the legend what INSTANCE 1 or INSTANCE 2 are.

I did try and look at the very specific help text here:

[image]

But I do not know what the *classification frame* is or see a *Change* button.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In QGIS 3.16.0 I did as described in the docs (in my case I
   applied a graduated rendering of the value "Tabell_Endring_Areal"):

   [image]
2. Click on the Symbol-button to the change it (I'm using circle) and
   then on the Data defined override-button and choose Assistant:

   [image]
3. Choose source (the value (field) you want its symbol to be
   proportional. This is *another* value than the "graduated one" used
   in step 1), start and end value and output. NB. Set a minimum size
   for NULL:

   [image]
4. Go back to the Layer styling-window and click on Advanced and
   Data-defined Size Legend:

   [image]
5. Choose Separated or collapsed legend. The appearance in the Layers
   panel will change accordingly.

   [image]

Now the symbols also will be visible in the Layout:

[image]

So there is no bug, but it may not seem too intuitive to have to set a size when null. @gioman revealed this in a comment at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39882