# Symbol missing in legend when adding to layout map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, legend, mapping

I am new to QGIS and I am trying to make a map of India displaying some values. I want to have a legend, and I customised the legend in layers panel, the Layers panel clearly displays my legend. But the issue is when I try to make a map  with that, legend displays no symbols, only values are displayed with the legend. I am adding the screenshot of my Layers panel showing the symbols and layout map without the symbols. I am using QGIS version 3.18.1.

Layers panel showing symbols:

[image]

Layout map legend without symbols:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you explain your process and what you have tried. Otherwise, we don't have much to go off of. Have you seen the docs on how to do [proportional symbols](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#proportional-symbol-and-multivariate-analysis)? Or you could just follow this very [detailed answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376022/legend-symbol-is-not-visable-in-layout-composer-when-styling-points-with-two-dif#answer-378656) to a similar question. I followed it and had no problems displaying the symbols in the legend.

Ultimately, after completing the initial steps that create your symbol you will want to go under Advanced and click *Data-Defined Size Legend...* to get this menu:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry I think it is an issue regarding the size of my symbols, it was very large so the layout map couldn't display it. A few minutes ago I changed the size of my symbols and tried to add the legend. Now the legend is showing the symbols. Thank you.